# Can a Custom Taxonomy be named "category" like normal Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Is it fine to call a Custom Taxonomy (created to store Custom Post Type) "Category" like it is already the case for *normal* Posts, and to use all the terminology ("Categories", "Create a new category", etc.) ? I mean, are there any risk of instability or compatibility issues if I do so ?
Like for example : taxonomy overridden, etc…

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for but fwiw you *can* associate the default 'category' taxonomy with your new Custom Post Type - see the examples on this page that show how to associate 'category' with Pages as well as Posts, for example: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy_for_object_type/

Comment: Very useful, thanks ! I'm just wondering if the performance are the same. I mean, using an already registered taxonomy (category in this case) might have consequences with the queries, the database, etc., if I use this taxonomy for a big amount of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. "Category" is one of WordPress reserved terms.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

**Reserved terms**

- attachment_id
- author
- author_name
- calendar
- cat
- **category**
- category__and
- category__in
- category__not_in

Comment: Thanks for the link : it's exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: Note that there's nothing stopping you from using the word "Category" in the label(s) of the taxonomy; you just can't do, eg, `register_taxonomy( 'category', $args );` . Be aware, though, that using "Category" in the label(s) may cause confusion to your users. I'd recommend using something like "{Post Type} Category" instead.